# Drop event not firing?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a simple Kanban board. I am trying to attach events('dragstart', 'dragend', 'drop') to the boards instead of each tasks so that we have minimum number of event listeners. My 'dragstart' and 'dragend' events are working but not the 'drop' event. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
const addTaskBtnEl = document.getElementById("add-task-btn");
const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container"); 
const boardEls = document.querySelectorAll(".board"); 
const todoBoardEl = document.getElementById("todo-board"); 
const state = { draggingTask: "" };

addTaskBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  const taskItemText = prompt("Enter the task: "); 

  if (taskItemText) { 
    const p = document.createElement("p"); 
    p.classList.add("task"); 
    p.setAttribute("draggable", true); 

    const textNode = document.createTextNode(taskItemText); 
    p.appendChild(textNode); 

    todoBoardEl.appendChild(p); 
  } 
});

boardEls.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("drop", handleDropTask)); 
boardEls.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStartTask)); 
boardEls.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEndTask)); 

function handleDragStartTask(e) { 
  if (e.target.className === "task") {
    console.log("dragging start"); 
  } 
}

function handleDragEndTask(e) {
  console.log("dragging end");
}

function handleDropTask(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('dropped')
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; 
} 

body { 
  margin: 0; 
} 

.container { 
  height: 80vh; 
  display: flex; 
  gap: 10px; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}

.board { 
  height: 80vh; 
  width: 300px; 
  border: 2px solid; 
  border-radius: 10px; 
  padding: 10px; 
} 

.task { 
  border: 2px solid; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  background-color: blanchedalmond; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id="add-task-btn">Add Task</button>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Todo Board -->
    <div id="todo-board" class="board">
    </div>

    <!-- In Progress Board  -->
    <div class="board">
    </div>

    <!-- Done Board -->
    <div class="board"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Also, do you think it is possible to attach event listeners only to container div? I tried that but was facing the same issue of drop not triggering.
Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drop_event

Comment: @Teemu, I tried to do as they have done in their example. My each board is a taget board and I've added event listener to all of them. 
( boardEls.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("drop", handleDropTask));  )
In this case, I just want to console log that something has been dropped. But the handler isn't getting triggered.

Comment: You're not listening `dragover` event on drop target, its default action has to be prevented in order to fire `drop` event ("_prevent default to allow drop_"). Also, `drop` is listened on the drop target, not on the draggable element.

Comment: @Teemu, hmm... adding `dragover`  event listener caused `drop` to work!  Thank you so much!